# mapping a vector of strings to integer

Tags: c++, string, vector, stl

I am using these data structures

```
map < vector < string > , int > hash;
vector < string > element;
```

After I created the element vector.
When I try to use this data structures-

```
if(hash[element].count()==0) // line 1
hash.insert(pair< <vector<string>,int>(element,1)); // line 2
```

I get the following errors-

Line 1:

> [Error] request for member `count` in `hash.std::map<_Key, _Tp,
>   _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, int, std::less<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >,
>   std::allocator<std::pair<const std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >,
>   int> > >((*(const key_type*)(& element)))`, which is of non-class type
>   `std::map<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, int>::mapped_type
>   {aka int}`

Line 2:

> wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)

Comment: Switch the parameters:  `map<int, vector<string>> hash;` It means.. the integer will be used as the key.. and the vector of strings will be the value for that key. I doubt you meant to use a vector of strings as the key. If you did, then ignore me completely.

Comment: And count the brackets on line 2 - there's a redundant opening bracket.

Comment: I *think* you want: `hash.insert(pair<vector<string>,int>(element,1));` And I agree it looks lik a very unusual key to be using.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
if(hash[element].count()==0) // line 1
```

needs to be:

```
if(hash.count(element)==0) // line 1
```

The line

```
hash.insert(pair< <vector<string>,int>(element,1)); // line 2
// Remove the   ^^^ Extra <
```

needs to be:

```
hash.insert(pair<vector<string>,int>(element,1)); // line 2
```

or, still better:

```
hash.emplace(element,1);
```

Comment: @ChrisDrew, thanks for the upvote. Yes, `emplace` would work too.